# Regex for replacing character in certain contexts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which simplified looks like this:

```
This string took 5.5 seconds to write.
```

I want to replace every occurrence of [0-9].[0-9] with [0-9],[0-9] to change the decimal separator, i.e. the example string would become

```
This string took 5,5 seconds to write.
```

When I try this

```
mystr.replace(/[0-9]\.[0-9]/g, ',')
```

it obviously replaces the numbers, which I want to keep, and when I do this

```
mystr.replace(/\./g, ',')
```

the period in the end gets replaced. Periods could potentially also appear in other contexts such as '\s.\s' or 'a.b'.

Is there a nice solution for how to replace periods appearing between two digits without affecting anything else?

Comment: `mystr.replace(/([0-9])\.([0-9])/g, '$1,$2')`

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski that does exactly what I wanted, thanks so much!